# docker-compose "No such file or directory" for sh-command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am setting up `docker-for-windows` on my private pc.

When I set it up a while ago on my office laptop I had the same issue but it just stopped happening.

So I am stuck with this:

I have a docker-working project (on my other computer) with a `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    env_file: ./docker-compose.env
    command: bash ./run_web_local.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/project
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    links:
      - db
      - rabbit
    restart: always
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as 'builder'
FROM node:8-alpine as builder

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

# build backend
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
ADD package-lock.json /tmp/package-lock.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /backend-app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /backend-app

### STAGE 2: Setup ###
FROM python:3

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -U pip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt

# Set env variables used in this Dockerfile (add a unique prefix, such as DOCKYARD)
# Local directory with project source
ENV PROJECT_SRC=.
# Directory in container for all project files
ENV PROJECT_SRVHOME=/srv
# Directory in container for project source files
ENV PROJECT_SRVPROJ=/srv/project

# Create application subdirectories
WORKDIR $PROJECT_SRVPROJ
RUN mkdir media static staticfiles logs

# make folders available for other containers
VOLUME ["$PROJECT_SRVHOME/media/", "$PROJECT_SRVHOME/logs/"]

# Copy application source code to SRCDIR
COPY $PROJECT_SRC $PROJECT_SRVPROJ

COPY --from=builder /backend-app/node_modules $PROJECT_SRVPROJ/node_modules

# Copy entrypoint script into the image
WORKDIR $PROJECT_SRVPROJ

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["./run_web.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.env:**

```
C_FORCE_ROOT=True
DJANGO_CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit:5672//
DJANGO_DATABASE_ENGINE=django.db.backends.mysql
DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME=project-db
DJANGO_DATABASE_USER=project-user
DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD=mypassword
DJANGO_DATABASE_HOST=db
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1,localhost
DJANGO_DEBUG=True
DJANGO_USE_DEBUG_TOOLBAR=off
DJANGO_TEST_RUN=off
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
```

**run_web_local.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo django shell commands
python ./manage.py migrate
echo Starting django server on 127.0.0.1:8000
python ./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

When I call `docker-compose up web` I get the following error:

> web_1          | bash: ./run_web_local.sh: No such file or directory

- I checked the line endings, they are UNIX
- the file exists on the file system as well as inside the container
- I can call `bash run_web_local.sh` from my windows powershell and inside the container
- I changed the UNIX permissions inside the container
- I left out the `bash` in the `command` in the `docker-compose` command. And tried with backslash, no dot etc.
- I reinstalled docker
- I tried switching to version 3
- docker claims to have a connection to my shared drive C

And: The exact same setup **works** on my other laptop.

Any ideas? All the two million github posts didn't solve the problem for me.

Thanks!

**Update**

Removing `volumes:` from the docker-compose makes it work [like stated here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2548) but I don't have an instant mapping. That's kind of important for me...

Comment: Can you share github repo if you have?

Comment: Sorry, it's a company project so it's not an open repo :( But I tried it with several projects, all have the same issue and all of them work on my other pc.

Comment: Isn't that meant to be ’bash -c ./XXX.sh’? Emphasis on "-c"

Comment: `bash -c ./run_web_local.sh` doesn't change it. Same error.

Comment: so, instead try `cat ./run_web_local.sh` or `ls ./` and see if things really are as they seem.

Comment: WTF... you are right. `ls` returns nothing. How is this possible? Any why is it working everywhere else? I executed `touch test.txt` and this shows up. So docker-compose really thinks that the dir is empty...

Comment: @Ron, Can you try using ${PWD}/run_web_local.sh, or you can print PWD, so that you can come to know what's the actual path it's referring to.

Comment: The path is correct but it's empty. Removing `volumes` from the `docker-compose` makes it start but I lose the instant mapping. That would be important for me as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had same issue recently and the problems goes away using any advanced editor and changing line ending to unix style on sh entrypoint scripts.

In my case, not sure why, because git handle it very well depending on linux or windows host I ended up in same situation.
If you have files mounted in container and host(in windows)
it dependes on how you edit them may be changed to linux from inside container but that affects outside windows host.
After that git stated file .sh changed but no additions no deletions.
a graphical compare tool showed up that only new line where changed.

Another workaround to trouble shooting you can start your container overriden entrypoint script by sh for example and then from there you can check on the started container how linux sees the entrypoint script, even  you can test it and will see exact same error.

Comment: it seems that by default, on a windows env git will be "helpful" and convert all files downloaded from a repo to windows eol. You can manually change those files with notepad++ "Edit | EOL Conversion", but a long term solution is to add a .gitattributes to the top level of the project to tell git to do Unix eol for shell scripts - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71674232/8127899

Comment: Changing line ending for .sh file from CRLF to LF from VS Code did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should issue the following command before cloning the repository:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

This will change the line-ending to UNIX-style.

Then clone the repository and proceed.

Comment: An explanation why we should do this would be nice :)

Answer (score 2):

If possible can you please provide all the files related to this, so that i can try to reproduce the issue.

Seems like command is not executing is the dir where run_web_local.sh exist.

You can check the current workdir by replacing command in docker-compose.yml as 
`command: pwd && bash ./run_web_local.sh`

Comment: Great idea! Unfortunately the `pwd` shows `/srv/project` so this is correct. What file do you need?

Comment: Dockerfile you are building, env file and sh file.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the bash file is not in the root path or in the root path of workdir.
Check where is it in the container and verify if the path is correct.

Comment: Path is correct. Locally it's on the same level as the `docker-compose.yml`. I changed the path to the containers path but didn't work as well.

Comment: in the Dockerfile is specify the `WORKDIR /srv/project`?

Comment: Yes, `WORKDIR /srv/project`

Answer (score 1):

On thing I noticed in Ubuntu 18.04.3 is that you need to install docker-compose on top of docker.io to get docker-compose to work

- sudo apt install docker.io
- sudo apt install docker-compose

After I did that, I got docker-compose [filename.yml] up to work without issue

Answer (score -1):

Do not use -d at the end.
Instead of this command
**docker-compose -f start_tools.yaml up –d**
Use
**docker-compose -f start_tools.yaml up**