# Issue with line endings when developing on a Windows but running on a UNIX docker container

Tags: bash, docker, unix, line-endings

My team are building our first docker based .NET app and have written a bash script that runs as part of the build process (from the dockerfile). We are all on Windows 10 machines.

When the bash script runs, it throws an error:
`/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

From my research, this appears to be because of line endings being Windows line endings, not UNIX based. I was able to fix this by converting the endings using Notepad++ and the script ran fine. However, when I went into SourceTree to see the changed files, it briefly showed as a changed file (with something saying it couldn't detect changes). Once I clicked the stage file button, it disappeared as if there wasn't any changed files.

How do I resolve this? I can see a line endings setting in GIT but not sure what the right setting should be.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably looking for the `.gitattributes` file.

It allows you to set in which files you want which line endings.

Read more here: [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)

Answer (score 6):

Using [dos2unix](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/dos2unix-removing-hidden-windows-characters-from-files/) will help you with this problem. What dos2unix does is it removes the hidden windows characters that you encounter (^M).

> Windows-based text editors put special characters at the end of lines
> to denote a line return or newline. Normally harmless, some
> applications on a Linux server cannot understand these characters and
> can cause the service to not respond correctly.

If you don't have dos2unix in your linux machine yet:

Install dos2unix

```
apt install dos2unix
```

Run dos2unix on your problematic file

```
dos2unix your_problematic_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem isn't really converting the line endings. I know how to do that. My issue is that we develop on Windows machines, so I converted the endings but GIT won't recognize the file having been changed for me to check it in for other developers to pick it up.

Answer (score 5):

Add a `.gitattributes` file to the top of your repository with the following contents.

```
* text=auto
*.sh text eol=lf
*.conf text eol=lf
```

[Source](https://blog.programster.org/fixing-docker-volume-windows-line-endings-on-bash-scripts)